# Memory Leak using URLSessionDataTask and @Published

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting, nsurlsession

I have this APIRepresentative class as a singleton `EnvironmentObject` in my SwiftUI app. The class has `@Published var` that holds all `InsightData` structs by ID.

Even in a view that has no dependencies on `insightData`, repeatedly calling the `getInsightData` function causes memory usage in my app to rise by about 200Kb or so each time. Over the lifetime of my app, this will cause memory usage to balloon to several gigabytes.

Here's the kicker: The memory leak vanishes when I remove the `@Published` modifier for `insightData`. I can then call my function as much as I like, with no increase in memory usage. Any idea why that is the case? I would very much like to keep the `@Published` property.

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

final class APIRepresentative: ObservableObject {
    private static let baseURLString = "https://apptelemetry.io/api/v1/"

    @Published var insightData: [UUID: InsightDataTransferObject] = [:]

    // More published properties
    // ...
}


extension APIRepresentative {
    func getInsightData(for insight: Insight, in insightGroup: InsightGroup, in app: TelemetryApp, callback: ((Result<InsightDataTransferObject, TransferError>) -> ())? = nil) {
        let timeWindowEndDate = timeWindowEnd ?? Date()
        let timeWindowBeginDate = timeWindowBeginning ?? timeWindowEndDate.addingTimeInterval(-60 * 60 * 24 * 30)

        let url = urlForPath("apps", app.id.uuidString, "insightgroups", insightGroup.id.uuidString, "insights",
                             insight.id.uuidString,
                             Formatter.iso8601noFS.string(from: timeWindowBeginDate),
                             Formatter.iso8601noFS.string(from: timeWindowEndDate)
        )

        let request = self.authenticatedURLRequest(for: url, httpMethod: "GET")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                let decoded = try! JSONDecoder.telemetryDecoder.decode(InsightDataTransferObject.self, from: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else {
                        print("Self is gone")
                        return
                    }

                    var newInsightData = self.insightData
                    newInsightData[decoded.id] = decoded

                    self.insightData = newInsightData
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

// more retrieval functions for the other published properties
// ...
```

Here's the [full file](https://gist.github.com/winsmith/fd5a556195680098ee2decff4ccffd16) but I'm pretty sure I included all relevant parts in this whittled down version

Comment: Do you mean that something within those 10 lines of code must be responsible for your memory leak?

Comment: I‘m pretty sure, yes. Maybe the title should be „Memory Leak WHILE using...“?

Comment: No.  There's nothing wrong with the title.  It's hard for me to believe that something within those lines is causing it.  There must be something you aren't telling.  Isn't it the case that you are calling `URLSession` numerous times repeatedly?

Comment: I'm interested in your topic.  But I'm going to bed.  I'll take another look in several hours.

Comment: It's hard for me to believe as well, that's why I'm turning to StackOverflow. Yes I *am* calling this function repeatedly, to update my app with data from the server. Usually not in a while loop and not as often of course.

Comment: Show us how you repeatedly call it, then.  I'm really going to bed right now, though.  Talk to you later.

Comment: For debug purposes I'm calling it like this: 

```
while true {
    api.getInsightData(for: insight, in: insightGroup, in: app)
    sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: I have doubts that the reason is in provided code. Would you show all parts of code that depends on or uses `insightData`?

Comment: yes, I'll edit the question to zoom out a little bit.

Comment: I don't see how or where you repeatedly call `URSession` in your GitHub code.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would assume that memory would grow given this line:

```
        self.insightData[decoded.id] = decoded
```

You're storing new values for every download, and don't seem to ever release them unless `decoded.id` repeats. That's not a leak; that's just storing more data in memory.

That said, if you're testing this with your `while` loop, you should expect substantial memory growth because you never drain the autorelease pool. The autorelease pool is drained when the current run loop cycle completes, but this `while` loop never ends. So you'd want to create a new pool:

```
while true {
    @autoreleasepool { 
        api.getInsightData(for: insight, in: insightGroup, in: app)
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: In this while loop, I'm setting the same ID each time, so that shouldn't be the case. Autoreleasepool makes no difference. However, I found something else: it seems to be related to Comine. I'll update the question

Comment: If you believe you have an actual retain cycle, check the memory graph debugger in Xcode. It's quite good at tracking down the symptoms (though not the cause). https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: The memory graph shows no cycles, and none of the little exclamation marks in the issues navigator. Do you think this could not be related to a retain cycle at all? The fact that stuff just works when I stop marking the property as @Published seems to indicate so as well.

Comment: I would first suspect whatever is observing the object. But if nothing is observing the object, I wouldn't ignore the possibility of a bug in `@Published` (there was a time when I would never jump to "Apple bug," but those days are past, and I don't really trust Combine yet). You might try reimplementing `@Published` by hand. It should just require adding `{ willSet { objectWillChange.send() }}` to your property definition. At least that would give you some more hooks to explore what's happening.

Comment: That sounds like a very good idea to me, thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: Adding `{ willSet { objectWillChange.send() }}` also causes the memory to rise. It kinda *has* to be a subscribing object now.

Comment: I removed ALL objects, views, structs that access the property. The leak is still there.